# Update user password via JDBC not working

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

This is the relevant bit of code,

```
createconn = new CreateConnection();
con = createconn.connect_to_database();
String SQL = "UPDATE User SET Password = SHA2(?,512) WHERE Login = ? AND Password = SHA2(?,512)";
stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
stmt.setString(1, NewPassword);
stmt.setString(2, Login);
stmt.setString(3, CurrentPassword);
int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + count);
```

count always is set to 0, i.e., no rows are updated, even when current password is correct. What's worse, no exception is generated. (even when current password is wrong)

When I use a fixed statement (using fixed values for the three parameters), the code works, just not when written like this.

This whole code is inside a function which takes the three parameters as arguments.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: porobably no usert with given login and hash

Comment: There is. When I run the same query in MySQL terminal, (using values instead of ?), it works

Comment: Do you need to use the existing password as well, in the condition? Can you try providing the login only and see if it works, just to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Try trint the parameters passed into the method just after execution.

Comment: Where do you set the variables in `stmt.setString(1, NewPassword);
stmt.setString(2, Login);
stmt.setString(3, CurrentPassword);` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland below statement.

Comment: @Nikhil maybe some sort of encoding issue. Does password have some sort of non ASCII characters? Verify that vairables has expected values as well (and no blank chars)

Comment: "below statement" with set i meant initialize @Antoniossss you know `String s = new String("string");` or `String s = "String";`

Comment: Thank you very much all of you. I figured out what the error was. Login parameter was being passed in as null. I fixed it, but am now stuck with something else. 1. How to check if SQL cannot find any statement to update? For example if the combination of Login and Password is wrong. No exception is thrown. Is checking count the only way? 2. It looks like the old password works till the user logs in at least once with the new password (I'm not invalidating the session on password change), using j_security_check. Is this a separate question? Let me know if it is.

Comment: Told ya to check that.

Answer (score 1):

PASSWORD is a reserved word, maybe the workbench is a bit more lenient/intelligent. Try adding back ticks around.

```
`Password`
```

Comment: "The following list shows the keywords and reserved words in MySQL 8.0, along with changes to individual words from version to version. Reserved keywords are marked with (R)." check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) if password was reserved would it would had have a `(R)` behide it, password is just a keyword..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes both USER and PASSWORD I would myself not dare to use (for cleanliness), but should not pose a problem. One can do `SELECT SHA2('...', 512)` to check the database. The error? Failed commit on password on INSERT. PreparedStatement `stmt` reused for other statements. Closes forgotten.